# How do I send a gmail email count to google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, gmail, gmail-api

I get sales confirmation emails from my store in gmail and would like to count these in google analytics.

Essentially I want to send an event whenever an email with subject containing "has just purchased" comes in. This should be fairly straight forward but I am not used to code for APIs (like gmail API).

I tried the more obvious solutions like adding a tag with google tag manager to track sales of course, but the store page prevents (or interferes with) code execution.

Zapier offers a solution that works but is not free.

Any ideas how to pull this off?

Answer (score 0):

> Essentially I want to send an event whenever an email with subject containing "has just purchased" comes in.

Your going to have to use the Gmail api to check your email for emails containing that subject.  Once they have arived you could use the same system to send a tracking hit to google analytics using the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en).

Things to note:

1. Gmail api does not support service accounts unless your email address is coming from a gsuite domain. If it is then you can set up a service account to read your emails.  If not you will need to authorize your application once store your refresh token then your application will be able to read your gmail account using the refresh token to request a new access token as needed.
2. When creating your application make sure to set this application as internal only or you will be required to verify this application and application verification for gmail scopes is quite expensive.
3. When using the measurement protocol remember to disable bot filter on your google analytics account or the hits will not show up.